# Why would renormalization still optimize the objective?

Tags: probability, derivatives, optimization

I want to maximize the following objective
$$
\arg\max_\pi\mathbb E_{\pi(a)}[r(a)-\log\pi(a)]\tag1\\
s.t. \int\pi(a)da=1
$$
I've leaned a way to solve this problem according to Page 26 of [this lecture](http://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse-fa18/static/slides/lec-15.pdf)(albeit I simplify the problem a bit):

Taking the gradient of (1), and setting it to zero, this gives us
$$
\begin{align}
r(a)-\log\pi(a)-1&=0\\
\pi(a)&=\exp(r(a)-1)\tag 2
\end{align}
$$
Following the lecture, this means $\pi(a)\propto\exp(r(a))$. Because $\pi(a)$ is a probability distribution and integrates to 1, we renormalize Equation (2) and get 
$$
\pi(a)={\exp(r(a))\over\int\exp(r(a))da}\tag3
$$
I understand that Equation (2) is the minimizer of (1) without the constraint. What I'm confused about is why Equation (2) suggests $\pi(a)\propto\exp(r(a))$? Why renormalizing Equation (2) would makes it the minimizer of (1) under the constraint?

Comment: I did not look at the lecture notes, so apologies in advance if I'm way off, and pls take this with a grain of salt:  in (1), if you rescale $\pi$ to $k \pi$, that just makes $E[r(a) - \log k \pi(a)] = E[r(a) - \log \pi(a)] - \log k$, and the extra constant term does not affect arg max.

Comment: Thank you @antkam, I see your point and this makes sense to me. I'm wondering whether this is applicable to general optimization problems or specific to this problem? BTW, you forgot $\pi(a)$ in the expectation, albeit it does not change the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do some variational calculus here.

We want to solve constrained optimization problem:

$
\left \{ \begin{array}{rcl}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \pi(a) \cdot (r(a) - \log \pi(a)) \ da \to \max\limits_{\pi(a)} \\
s.t. \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \pi(a) \ da = 1
\end{array} \right .
$

Construct Lagrangian: $L(a, \pi, \pi^{\prime}) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \underbrace{\pi(a)(r(a) - \log \pi(a)) + \lambda \cdot (\pi(a) - 1)}_{F(a, \pi, \pi^{\prime})} \ da$.

It's known from variational calculus, that in order to minimize $L$, you need to solve $\frac{\delta L}{\delta \pi} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial \pi} - \frac{d}{da} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \pi^{\prime}} = 0$.

So we have: $\frac{\delta L}{\delta \pi} = r(a) - \log \pi(a) - 1 + \lambda = 0 \Rightarrow \pi(a) = e^{r(a)} \cdot e^{\lambda - 1}$

Plug this into constraint: $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \pi(a) \ da = e^{\lambda - 1} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} e^{r(a)} \ da = 1 \Rightarrow e^{\lambda - 1} = \frac{1}{\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} e^{r(a)} \ da}$

So: $\boxed{\pi(a) = \frac{e^{r(a)}}{\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} e^{r(a)} \ da}}$